# X.509 certificate serial number to hex conversion

Tags: python, pyopenssl

I'm trying to get the serial number for an X.509 certificate using Pythons OpenSSL library.

If I load my cert like this:

```
 x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, cert)
```

Then print the serial number like this:

```
print x509.get_serial_number()
```

It looks like this:

```
5.283978953499081e+37
```

If I convert it to hex like this:

```
'{0:x}'.format(int(5.283978953499081e+37))
```

It returns this:

```
27c092c344a6c2000000000000000000
```

However, using OpenSSL from the command line to print the certificates serial number returns this.

```
27:c0:92:c3:44:a6:c2:35:29:8f:d9:a2:fb:16:f9:b7
```

Why is half of the serial number being converted to zeros?

Comment: Are you sure certificate is encoded with ASN1? Which version of OpenSSL are you using?

Comment: Try `'%x' % cert.get_serial_number()`. Should help.

Comment: Thanks very much - Well that fixed it. What does the "%x" % actually do here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'%x' % cert.get_serial_number()
```

`'%x' %` formats string like `'{0:x}'.format(cert.get_serial_number())`